# Сравнение введенной строки со строками из структуры struct NASM

Tags: ассемблер, nasm

Мне нужно вывести из структуры номер строки, которая эквивалентна введенной строчке с консольного ввода, если таких строк нет, то написать сообщение об её отсутствии. Я не могу освоить эти структуры.
Использую NASM на Win32, в качестве линкера golink.
Вот мой код. Помогите, пожалуйста

```
global Start
STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE equ -11
STD_INPUT_HANDLE  equ -10
EXTERN GetStdHandle
EXTERN WriteFile
EXTERN ExitProcess
EXTERN ReadConsoleA
extern lfwrit

section .text

Start:
    ;получение хэндла вывода
    push dword STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE
    call GetStdHandle
    mov [hstdout],eax
    mov eax, 1000h
    
    ;WriteFile(hstdout, txt, 7, &actlen, NULL)
    push 0
    push actlen
    push msg_len
    push msg
    push dword [hstdout]
    call WriteFile

    ;получение хэндла ввода
    push dword STD_INPUT_HANDLE
    call GetStdHandle
    mov [hstdin],eax

    ;ReadConsoleInputA(hstdin,buf,buf_len,0);
    push 0
    push actlen2 ;Pointer to a DWORD for number of characters read to be returned
    push 11
    push string
    push dword [hstdin]
    call ReadConsoleA


    mov esi, records
    mov ecx, [records_count]
    
search:
    
    `mov esi, [eax+record.txt]; беру текст`
    mov edi, string; введенную строку
    mov edx, 11; максимальная длина
    cld
    repe cmpsb; сравниваю строки
    jecxz success
    add eax, 15; добавляю 15 так как txt 11 байт + 4 байта num
    loop search
    
    ;WriteFile(hstdout, txt, 7, &actlen, NULL)
    ;Fail
    push 0
    push actlen
    push fail_msg_len
    push fail_msg
    push dword [hstdout]
    call WriteFile

    jmp _exit

success:
    
    `mov ecx, esi; в есх адрес текста
    add ecx, record.num;`
    ;WriteFile(hstdout, txt, 7, &actlen, NULL)
    ;num
    push 0
    push actlen
    push dword 4
    push ecx
    push dword [hstdout]
    call WriteFile

    call lfwrit

_exit:
    ;ExitProcess(0)
    push dword 0
    call ExitProcess


section .bss
    string resb 11; место для введенной строки
    struc record;структура число - текст
        .txt resb 11
        .num resd 1
      
    endstruc

section .data
    ;хэндлы
    hstdout dd 0
    hstdin dd 0
    actlen dd 1; что-то для ввода
    actlen2 dd 1; что-то для вывода

    msg db 'Entex text: ', 0ah
    msg_len equ $ - msg
    fail_msg db 'Note with this text doestn exist', 0ah
    fail_msg_len equ $ - fail_msg
;инициализация структуры
records:
    istruc record
        at record.txt, db 'odin'
        at record.num, dd 1
    iend
    istruc record
        at record.txt, db 'devyat'
        at record.num, dd 9
    iend
    
    records_count dd 2
```

Не получается получить строку для сравнения в данном фрагменте

```
mov esi, [eax+record.txt]; беру текст
```

и не понимаю как, потом получить по этой строке num из структуры

```
mov ecx, esi; в есх адрес текста
add ecx, record.num;
```

после сборки и запуска при вводе строки програма зависает на секунду и завершается

Comment: слишком много кода. ищи узкое место и спрашивай конкретно.

Comment: Немного подредактировал вопрос, мне непонятно как в регистр esi занести строку из структуры для дальнейшего сравнения с введенной строкой и как потом получить число соответствующее этой строке в структуре, и вывести ее в виде числа

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не знаю как в NASM, но вот аналогичный алго на FASM'e (у них синтаксис почти схожий). Поскольку во всех структурах поля одинакового размера, то под текст резервируем 8 байт, а под номер dword = 4. Теперь на старте ставим указатель на первую структуру, и для перехода на следующую - просто в цикле прибавляем к этому указателю 12.

Если сравнение дало результат, то прибавив к указателю 8 (резерв для текста) и обернув его в квадратные скобки, берём значение из найденной структуры. Для ввода-вывода удобней использовать функции из msvcrt.dll, как в примере ниже:

```
format   pe console
include 'win32ax.inc'
entry    start
;//************
.data
;//<--------- Структуры (размер одной: 8+4=12 байт)
struct Record_1
  txt       db  'odin    '
  num       dd  1
ends
struct Record_2
  txt       db  'devyat  '
  num       dd  9
ends
;//<--------- Указатели на них
rec1        Record_1
rec2        Record_2

rec_count   dd  2
buff        db  16 dup(' ')

;//************
.code
start:
;// Запрос на ввод текста
       cinvoke  printf,<10,' Enter text: ',0>

;// Ввод текста длиною 8 символов в буфер
       cinvoke  scanf,<'%8s',0>,buff

;// scanf() вставляет терминальный нуль - уберём его
       mov      ecx,16           ;// размер буфера
       mov      edi,buff         ;// его адрес
       xor      al,al            ;// что искать = нуль
       repne    scasb            ;// поиск AL в EDI..
       mov      byte[edi-1],' '  ;// заменить нуль на пробел!

;// Сравниваем ввод с текстом из структур
       mov      esi,rec1.txt     ;// адрес первого txt-поля
@compare:                        ;//
       mov      ecx,8            ;// длина поиска (всего символов в поле)
       mov      edi,buff         ;// юзерский ввод (с чем сравнивать)
       push     esi              ;// (!)запомнить адрес очередной структуры
       repe     cmpsb            ;// Compare.. по длине ECX
       jcxz     @ok              ;// если нашли.

       pop      esi              ;// иначе: снимаем указатель
       add      esi,12           ;// прыгаем на сл.структуру
       dec      [rec_count]      ;// всего структур -1
       jnz      @compare         ;// повторить, если не нуль

;// Ошибка поиска и на выход
       cinvoke  printf,<' Text not found!',0>
       jmp      @exit

;//<----------- ОК! ----------------------------->
@ok:   pop      esi              ;// ESI = указатель на структуру с текстом
       mov      eax,[esi+8]      ;// взять в EAX поле "num" из этой структуры
       cinvoke  printf,<' Text Found! Num = %d',0>,eax

@exit: cinvoke  getch
       cinvoke  exit,0

;//************
section '.idata' import data readable
library  msvcrt,'msvcrt.dll'
import   msvcrt, printf,'printf',scanf,'scanf',getch,'_getch',exit,'exit'
```